# Reading file elements into an adjacency list

Tags: python, graph, adjacency-list

I have a file containing:

```
0 1 95.21
0 2 43.8
1 3 10.4
2 5 67.1
```

and I'm trying to create an adjacency list out of it. Where the first two lines represents the vertices connected to each other and the 3rd column represents the length of the edge. I want python to produce an output as such:

```
[[1, 95.21],[2, 43.8]] #starting from 0, 0 connects to 1 of length 95.21, and 0 connects to 2 of length 43.8

[[0, 95.21],[3, 10.4]] #for 1, 1 also connects to 0 of length 95.21, and 1 connects to 3 of length 10.4

[[0, 43.8],[5, 67.1]]  #for 2, 2 also connects to 0 of length 43.8, and 2 connects to 5 of length 67.1
```

I managed to write the code that produces the adjacency list:

```
filename2 = open("list.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8")
efile = filename2

adjList = [0] * 10
for i in range(10):
    adjList[i] = []

for line in efile:
    edgeEndpoints = line.split()
    adjList[int(edgeEndpoints[0])].append(int(edgeEndpoints[1]))
    adjList[int(edgeEndpoints[1])].append(int(edgeEndpoints[0]))
print(adjList)
```

giving me

```
[[1,2],[0,3],[0,5]]
```

but i couldn't think of a way of including the edge length. Instead of [1,2] i wanted

```
[[[1, 95.21],[2, 43.8]],[[0, 95.21],[3, 10.4]],[[0, 43.8],[5, 67.1]]
```

Would appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `append`ing a single integer, you should `append` a `list` that contains both integer and distance.

```
filename2 = open("list.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8")
efile = filename2

adjList = [0] * 10
for i in range(10):
    adjList[i] = []

for line in efile:
    edgeEndpoints = line.split()
    adjList[int(edgeEndpoints[0])].append([int(edgeEndpoints[1]), float(edgeEndpoints[2])])
    adjList[int(edgeEndpoints[1])].append([int(edgeEndpoints[0]), float(edgeEndpoints[2])])
print(adjList)
```

gives output:

```
$ python3 adjtest.py
[[[1, 95.21], [2, 43.8]], [[0, 95.21], [3, 10.4]], [[0, 43.8], [5, 67.1]], [[1, 10.4]], [], [[2, 67.1]], [], [], [], []]
```

however, I would pick @BoarGules's solution rather than this way, since it's clean and applicable to all possible inputs of this format.

Answer (score 2):

In this solution I tried to avoid having to know in advance how many nodes are in your data.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> adj_list = defaultdict(set)
>>> with open('list.txt') as f:
      for line in f:
        start,end,length = line.rstrip().split()
        adj_list[int(start)].add((int(end),float(length)))
        adj_list[int(end)].add((int(start),float(length)))
```

This gives the following result

```
>>> for k,v in adj_list.items():
    print(k,":",v) 

0 : set([(2, 43.8), (1, 95.21)])
1 : set([(3, 10.4), (0, 95.21)])
2 : set([(0, 43.8), (5, 67.1)])
3 : set([(1, 10.4)])
5 : set([(2, 67.1)])
```